# SQL Finding Dupe Names with Distinct ID

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct

I have a list of customers, and a bunch of them are duplicates ('Acme Inc', 'Acme, Inc', 'Acme Inc.', 'Acme, Inc.')  They all have different IDs.
BUT, each ID also has multiple addresses.  Something like...

```
+-------+---------------+-------------------+-----------+---+-------+
|ID     |Name           |Address            |City       |St |Zip    |
+-------+---------------+-------------------+-----------+---+-------+
|001    |Acme Inc       |123 Address St     |Columbus   |OH |43081  |
|001    |Acme Inc       |321 Street St      |Columbus   |OH |43081  |
|001    |Acme Inc       |456 Blanket Blvd   |Columbus   |OH |43081  |
|002    |Acme, Inc      |123 Babel St       |Columbus   |OH |43081  |
|002    |Acme, Inc      |321 Acorn Rd       |Columbus   |OH |43081  |
|002    |Acme, Inc      |456 Lancer Blvd    |Columbus   |OH |43081  |
|003    |Baker          |456 Blanket Blvd   |Columbus   |OH |43081  |
|004    |Peterson       |456 Blanket Blvd   |Columbus   |OH |43081  |
|005    |Plumbers Inc   |123 Address St     |Columbus   |OH |43081  |
|006    |Plumbers, LLC  |321 Street St      |Columbus   |OH |43081  |
|007    |Acme, Inc.     |123 Address St     |Columbus   |OH |43081  |
```

I have a function that normalizes the name so the first 6 would all be 'Acme' and the last two 'Plumbers'.

What I want is a list of the ID and Name where there are duplicate.  The goal is a report of records with unique IDs and duplicate names.

```
+-------+---------------+
|ID     |Name           |
+-------+---------------+
|001    |Acme Inc       |
|002    |Acme, Inc      |
|007    |Acme, Inc.     |
|005    |Plumbers Inc   |
|006    |Plumbers, LLC  |
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT [Name],
    ( SELECT strNew FROM [fn_strNorm](2, [Name]) ) AS [NewName] 
  FROM [Processed_Vendors] 
  WHERE 
    [VendorID] <> '' AND 
    [VendorID] IS NOT NULL AND 
    [Name]<> '' AND 
    [Name] IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY [NewName]
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY [NewName]
```

I also tried to put them into [dump_names] table and join the two, but I keep getting multiple records from the same ID

```
SELECT 
    pv.[VendorID], 
    pv.[Name]
  FROM [dupe_names] n 
  LEFT JOIN [Processed_Vendors] pv 
    ON pv.[Name] = n.[Name] 
ORDER BY pv.[Name]


SELECT 
    'Name Match' AS [Reason], 
    pv.[VendorID], 
    pv.[Name]
  FROM [dupe_names] n 
  LEFT JOIN [Processed_Vendors] pv 
    ON pv.[Name] = n.[Name] 
    AND ( SELECT strNew FROM [dbo].[fn_strNorm](2, pv.[Name]) ) = n.[NewName]
ORDER BY pv.[Name]
```

I think I'm overthinking this or the migraine I'm sporting is clouding my thinking.
Either way, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would use a CTE to find the distinct counts of name variants for each normalized name.  Then, join to your current table and retain only records which had more than one name variant.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [dbo].[fn_strNorm](2, Name) AS NmName, COUNT(DISTINCT Name) AS cnt
    FROM Processed_Vendors
    GROUP BY [dbo].[fn_strNorm](2, Name)
)

SELECT DISTINCT pv.ID, pv.Name
FROM Processed_Vendors pv
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON t.NmName = [dbo].[fn_strNorm](2, pv.Name)
WHERE t.cnt > 1;
```